# IntelliJ plugin failing to load templates

Tags: intellij-idea, plugins, dart

I am using IntelliJ (v2018.3) to create a Dart project. When I select a Dart project in the New Project dialog, IntelliJ seems to get stuck "loading Dart project templates".

I checked the idea.log file. Apparently, something in the Dart plugin is causing the following failure:

```
2018-11-25 23:27:54,132 [  41721]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - com/intellij/javascript/debugger/execution/JavascriptDebugConfigurationType 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/intellij/javascript/debugger/execution/JavascriptDebugConfigurationType
    at com.jetbrains.lang.dart.projectWizard.DartGeneratorPeer.lambda$startLoadingTemplates$2(DartGeneratorPeer.java:108)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.intellij.javascript.debugger.execution.JavascriptDebugConfigurationType PluginClassLoader[Dart, 183.4284.122] com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader@2308abea
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:49)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
2018-11-25 23:27:54,136 [  41725]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3  Build #IC-183.4284.148 
2018-11-25 23:27:54,136 [  41725]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - JDK: 1.8.0_152-release; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o 
2018-11-25 23:27:54,136 [  41725]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - OS: Windows 10 
2018-11-25 23:27:54,142 [  41731]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - Plugin to blame: Dart version: 183.4284.122 
2018-11-25 23:27:54,142 [  41731]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - Last Action: WelcomeScreen.CreateNewProject
```

Clearly, something s failing in the plugin. Something is missing in the intallation?

Does anyone know how I might be able to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is logged as https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-35995.

As a workaround click Next to create an empty Dart project and then use the stagehand tool manually in Terminal to generate a sample project contents (https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/stagehand).

Comment: Thanks for creating the issue. I didn't realize it was one. I thought I might have screwed up the installation.

Comment: The Dart plugin with the fix has been published, please check for the plugin updates.